# if-clause causes "too-much-recursion-error"?

Tags: jquery, performance

before submitting my form to php, i´m doing an jquery check:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").submit(function(e){

    var vari1 = $("#inputhidden1").val();
    var vari2 = $("#inputhidden2").val();


    if(vari1 == 1) {
        if(vari2 == 1) {
            $("#submit").submit();
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

  });
});
```

If if every if-clause returned TRUE, the form action should be processed normally, but:
Instead my browser crashes and the console tell´s me:

```
to much recursion..
```

Anybody could help me?

greetings

Comment: You are calling submit inside itself, because of it you face the recursion

Comment: Wouldn't just returning true without `e.preventDefault()` do just that?

Comment: Within the `$("#submit").submit` function, if `vari1` and `vari2` are both true, you call `$("#submit").submit`.  Yup, that's too much recursion.

Comment: Your submit handler submits the form, which triggers the submit handler, which submits the form, ad infinitum.

Comment: @joachim what you mean exactly? sorry but i dont understand your point

Comment: @user3122124 Try replacing `$("#submit").submit();` with just `return true;`

Answer (score 2):

To submit your form only after check, just return true, if errors return false. Returning false will cancel the form's submition.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").submit(function(e){

    var vari1 = $("#inputhidden1").val();
    var vari2 = $("#inputhidden2").val();


    if(vari1 == 1) {
        if(vari2 == 1) {
            return true; // ok, submit
        }
    }
    return false; // error, cancel submit

  });
});
```

To make this smaller you could do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").submit(function(e){

    var vari1 = $("#inputhidden1").val();
    var vari2 = $("#inputhidden2").val();

    return (vari1 == 1 && vari2 == 1);

  });
});
```

**EDIT**

You got it all wrong.

Calling `$("#submit").submit();` just trigger the submit event, since your form check is inside this event, you dont need to call submit(), you're already inside the submit. What you need to do is `return true` to actualy "send" the submit, and `return false` to cancel the submit.

Read this page http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: where to put the submit-action in your second example?

Comment: In my second example, if both contition are true, true is returned and the form is submited. If one or both condition are false, false is returned and the form submition is canceled.

Comment: If you dont understund my second example, just use the first one.

Comment: yes but where do you say exactly that the form can be submitted in jquery?

Comment: i mean this part: " $("#submit").submit(); "